# how to use variable values out of then function in protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I am doing some calculations within "Then" function, whereas i am unable to take the output of calculation out of "Then" scope. I have given below a sample code where i am stuck.

```
var flag= true;
for(let i=1; i<leng, i++){
if(flag){     
 element(by.xpath("dsds")).click();
 --some delete fucntionality

 element(by.xpath("abc")).all(tagName('li').count().then(function(listLength) 
{
  if(listlength>1)
  {
   "doing some calculation
   flag=false;
  }
 });
}}
```

My problem: In above code, flag value is changing to false, which should restrict first IF block execution in 2nd iteration.
WHICH IS NOT HAPPENNING...because flag value is retained within THEN function and outside THEN function, flag value is always true.

How to solve this issue. Please someone guide me.

Comment: Can you describe your use case? Why are you looping a `count()` function? Usually you would count it once and use that value and that's it?

Comment: Actually i am doing alot of operation after first  IF block and before .count() statement. which i dont want to execute if second IF statement satisfies i.e listlength>1. its just that i have not mentioned those here to make it simpler.  To repeat my question: how can i use flag value from second IF block  to check condition in first IF ? :)

Comment: I have edited the sample code for better understanding of my situation

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has nothing to do with the *scope* of your `flag` variable and everything to do with *asynchronous JavaScript*.

Here is a simplified representation to help understand what is going on:

```js
var flag = false;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if(flag){
      console.log('Flag has been set!');
      break;
    } else {
      console.log('Flag not set yet :(');
      if(i === 3){
       flag = true;
      }
      setTimeout(function(){ console.log('Async callback finally happened! '); }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Like the `setTimeout()` function your `element(by.xpath("abc")).all(tagName('li').count().then(..)` functions call is also asynchronous. The only difference is `setTimeout()` is awaiting a callback and your function is waiting for the resolution of a promise.

**Notice:** how the `flag` variable is set to true and the `for` loop breaks long before the `setTimeout()` callback is fired. This demonstrates how the *scope* of your `flag` variable is not the issue. **What is likely happening in your code is your `for` loop is completing before your promise is resolved for the first time.**

**Additional takeaways** Notice from the console output that `setTimeout()` was called every single time your `for` loop iterated. That same result is happening for your code. You will call `element(by.xpath("abc")).all(tagName('li').count().then(..)` for every single iteration of your for loop which obviously is not desirable or performant.
Also you should stick with either using `var` OR `let` & `const` if you choose the latter it will help you prevent potential scoping issues.